# .Net MVC Global Filters with parameters don't work

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Custom Authorize implementation that receive in consctructor the name of Controllers that don't need to authorization:

```
public class ValidatePermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    ...

    public ValidatePermissionAttribute(params string[] optionalControllers)
    {
        this._optionalControllers = optionalControllers;
    }

    ...
}
```

In my global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new ValidatePermissionAttribute("Login", "Error"));
}
```

The problem is, when debug my app in `RegisterGlobalFilters` I see the parameters in my Filter. But when a Action is requested, the parameters is a `string[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional Filters in ASP.NET MVC 3 is the way to go. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx